# How to create a resource with label in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I need create 3 resources with same label dynamically.

```
label =['output']
resources=['output_1','output_2','output_3']
```

If I create a lock ,it will create  the resource also.
`lock(resource:'output_1')`  ->this will create a resource.

how to add a label to it?

Answer (score 0):

For using generate lock for yourself, you can use this command:

```
import org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager

LockableResourcesManager manager = LockableResourcesManager.get()

manager.createResourceWithLabel(your_label_name + number.toString(), your_label_name)
```

but you can customize this code for your purpose.

Answer (score -4):

To create three resources with the same label dynamically using a lock, you can follow these steps in a programming or scripting language that supports locking and resource creation. Here's a high-level example using Python:import threading

## Initialize a lock to ensure thread-safe resource creation

lock = threading.Lock()

## Function to create a resource with a given label

def create_resource(label, resource_name):
# Acquire the lock to ensure only one thread can create a resource at a time
with lock:
# Create the resource with the provided name
# You can replace this line with actual resource creation code
resource = f"Resource: {resource_name}"

```
    # Add the label to the resource
    resource_with_label = {label: resource}

    # You can replace this line with code to store or use the resource
    print(resource_with_label)
```

## Create three resources with the same label 'output'

for i in range(1, 4):
resource_name = f'output_{i}'
create_resource('output', resource_name)

In this example:

We initialize a lock to ensure that only one thread can create a resource at a time.

We define a create_resource function that takes a label and a resource name as arguments.

Inside the create_resource function, we acquire the lock using a with statement to ensure exclusive access for resource creation.

We create the resource (in this example, we simply generate a string with the resource name).

We add the label to the resource by creating a dictionary where the label is the key and the resource is the value.

You can replace the print statement with actual code to store or use the created resource.

Finally, we loop through and create three resources with the names 'output_1', 'output_2', and 'output_3', each with the label 'output'.

Comment: Please provide some references (documentation) for this information.